# SQL query to select all records from the last 5 years

Tags: mysql

I have a table called *recruits* that has columns including *first*, *last*, and *class*. The *first* and *last* columns are collectively the primary keys and represent a recruit's first and last names, respectively. The *class* column is the year in which the recruit has committed. Note that there can be multiple recruits in the same class, ie have the same *class* value.

I want to display all records from the most recent class--whatever it might be--as well as the ones from the four previous classes/years. I don't really want to hard-code a range of specific years because I would have manually change it whenever a new class/year comes along.

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if my description is too vague.

EDIT: I'm just using MySQL/Apache friends

Comment: Can you please post some example records?

Comment: No need, problem solved. Thanks for your interest in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using first+last as the PK means that a person cannot be recruited more than once.  It also prevents a second John Doe from recruiting when another has already recruited in a previous year.

```
select r.*
from
(
    # The 5 most recent classes
    select class
    from recruits
    group by class
    order by class desc
    limit 5
) c
inner join recruits r on r.class = c.class
order by class desc, `first`, `last`
```

I take it you mean last 5 years **present** in the data rather than last 5 calendar years from current.

Comment: Your assumption is correct and a variation of your query works for me. I realize the limitation of using only a recruit's first and last names as the primary key, but this database is just for a hobby project (ie, a football video game) so the likelihood of me recruiting two fictional players with the same name is pretty low. I have a question, though: What is the purpose of the `c` after the right parenthesis? Here's the query that I'm using: `SELECT *
FROM
(
 SELECT class
 FROM recruits WHERE pos IN ('C', 'G', 'T')
 GROUP BY class
 ORDER BY class ASC
 LIMIT 5
) C`

Comment: @Tim The 'c' is an alias to name the subquery if you need to use it later (it's required to name subqueries). In this case, c.class can properly refer to the class column from the subquery - to join back to recruits for the full record.

Comment: I see. It took me a while to realize that the query doesn't work (at least not with MySQL 5.1.41) without the subquery alias.

Comment: Here's the query that I'm using now for anyone who's curious. `"SELECT r.*
FROM (
    SELECT class
    FROM recruits 
    GROUP BY class
    ORDER BY class DESC
    LIMIT 5
) c
INNER JOIN RECRUITS r on r.class = c.class WHERE pos IN ('TE')
ORDER BY class DESC, last"` My previous modification only showed 5 records and not necessarily all records from the 5 most recent years.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your storing the year as `2006`, or `2011` and your using TSQL

```
select 
    First, Last, Class
From
    recruits
where
    class > datepart(yy,getdate())-5
```

This will get you anyone who joined post 2006

Comment: I should've specified that the _class_ values are the `bigint` datatype. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a specific SQL server, you can try this (should work on many RDBMS):

```
select *
  from recruits where class in
     (select distinct class from recruits order by recruits desc limit 2)
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL client/server version 5.1.41. I get the following error message with your query: _#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'_ Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, something like

```
SELECT first, last, class
  FROM (SELECT first, 
               last, 
               class, 
               dense_rank() over (order by class) rank_of_class
          FROM recruits)
 WHERE rank_of_class <= 5
```

will return all the information for the last 5 class values.

Comment: In tsql or pl:sql you'll want to use dense_rank otherwise you'll fall foul of the gaps between rankings

Comment: @Robb - Excellent point.  Edited my answer to make that change

Comment: MySQL version 5.1.41 apparently doesn't support your query; I get this error message: _#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by class) rank_of_class FROM recruits) WHERE rank_of_class <' at line 5_  Thanks for taking the time to answer my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you neeed something like:

```
Select
    *
From
    recruits
Where 
    class between DatePart(yy, getdate()) and DatePart(yy, getdate()) - 4
```

Might be able to get a little better answer depending on what exactly your using for your db.

This is transact sql from sql server.

Comment: I should've specified the datatype that I'm using for the _class_ column; it's not any of the actual date-related ones, just an integer. Thanks for your input.